# Kubuntu Login log in 20.04 not working

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, log

`Kubuntu Desktop` over 20.04 has this nice option. In `Settings > Notifications > Application - Configure > Plasma Workspace > Configure Events` , we can set Login attempts to " Log to a File ". It exists for Logouts too. Sadly, Login attempts are not recorded even after setting a text file for it. But Logout evens are correctly logged by `KNotify`.

[image]

It would nice to have the Login attempts logged as well to a text file of our choice. Is there any fix to it ? I thought 20.04.1 will bring some change. Looks like there is none. Any help will be great.

Comment: Does the log file exist? and was a bug filed?  It may have been fixed in a later release of KDE which you may see in *groovy* and later releases, but it needs to be reported first.

Comment: How can I do that ? Thanks. Log file is there 2B, untouched. Logout is active and big.